# Processing a nxn matrix with multiple batches of 10x10 in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a `matrix_function` which can do at max 10x10 operations at a given time. Now, I have a data frame with 25 points from where I need an output of 25x25 from that function.

Sample data:

```
id <- LETTERS[1:25]

set.seed(04)
value <- runif(25,30, 40)

data <- data.frame(id, value)

#dummy function for reproducibility
matrix_function <- function(x_id, x, y_id, y){
  
  computed_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
  
  for (i in 1:10) {
    
    for (j in 1:10) {
      computed_matrix[i,j] <- x[i] + y[j]
    }
    
  }
  
  
  colnames(computed_matrix) <- y_id
  rownames(computed_matrix) <- x_id
  
  return(computed_matrix)
}
```

Output:

```
> matrix_function(x_id=data$id[1:10], x=data$value[1:10], y_id=data$id[11:20], y=data$value[11:20])
         K        L        M        N        O        P        Q        R        S        T
A 73.40475 68.71801 66.85854 75.39869 70.01407 70.40903 75.56856 71.69788 75.48005 73.47503
B 67.63621 62.94946 61.08999 69.63015 64.24553 64.64048 69.80001 65.92934 69.71150 67.70648
C 70.48415 65.79740 63.93793 72.47808 67.09347 67.48842 72.64795 68.77728 72.55944 70.55442
D 70.32050 65.63376 63.77428 72.31444 66.92982 67.32477 72.48431 68.61363 72.39580 70.39077
E 75.68249 70.99575 69.13628 77.67643 72.29181 72.68677 77.84630 73.97562 77.75779 75.75277
F 70.15103 65.46428 63.60481 72.14497 66.76035 67.15530 72.31483 68.44416 72.22632 70.22130
G 74.79081 70.10407 68.24459 76.78475 71.40013 71.79508 76.95462 73.08394 76.86611 74.86108
H 76.60767 71.92093 70.06146 78.60161 73.21699 73.61195 78.77148 74.90080 78.68297 76.67795
I 77.03715 72.35041 70.49094 79.03109 73.64647 74.04143 79.20096 75.33028 79.11245 77.10743
J 68.27819 63.59145 61.73198 70.27213 64.88752 65.28247 70.44200 66.57132 70.35349 68.34847
```

My aim is to wrap the `matrix_function` with a function which can do all the operations for the points in batches (in this case there will be 7 batches) and give me a 25x25 matrix output.

So far I am trying with `for` loops but no luck.